# Javascript: Display Changing Text From Array

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I need function `function1()` to select a text from an array

```
var array1 = ['Bla','Blaa','Blabla','La',];
var result1 = array1[Math.floor(Math.random() * array1.length)];
```

Multiple times

```
var array1 = ['Bla','Blaa','Blabla','La',];
var result1 = array1[Math.floor(Math.random() * array1.length)];
var result2 = array1[Math.floor(Math.random() * array1.length)];
```

And then display `result1`

```
document.getElementById("paragraph").textContent = result1 ;
```

Then wait using setTimeout to wait 1 second and then display the second result

```
document.getElementById("paragraph").textContent = result2 ;
```

Can someone combine these unfinished pieces of code and convert it into a working function with a setTimeout command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got all that way and couldnt do the last bit?

```
document.getElementById("paragraph").textContent = result1 ;
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("paragraph").textContent = result2 ;
},1000);
```

[docs for `setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

Comment: Im amazed, the bit you've managed to do is infinitely more complex than a setTimeout :)

Comment: Yeah I learnt this stuff  from another part of my code but this is my first experience with setTimeout

Comment: function levfunction1() {
 var arraylev1 = ['Red','Blue','Green','Gold',];
 var resultlev1p1 = arraylev1[Math.floor(Math.random() * arraylev1.length)];
    var resultlev1p2 = arraylev1[Math.floor(Math.random() * arraylev1.length)];
 document.getElementById("headercolor").textContent = resultlev1p1 ;
 setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById("headercolor").textContent = "" ; 
 },1000);
 setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById("headercolor").textContent = resultlev1p2 ;
 },3000);
 setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById("headercolor").textContent = "" ; 
 },1000);
}

Comment: Any Idea why the 3rd (last SetTimeout function doesn't work.

Comment: They all fire off together, the first one does something after 1 second, but at the same time the third one will fire. `setTimeout` returns immediately remeber, it does not wait for the timeout to fire before moving to the next line of code.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "fix". Perhaps think about creating a new question, or updating this one. Feel free to ping me a link in these comments if you do.

Comment: Well is it possible to start a setTimeout after an earlier setTimeout

Comment: Sure, put the next one inside the `function` callback of the first one. `setTimeout(function(){ // do something; setTimeout(function(){//do next thing},1000)},1000)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the generated random number is as big as the `array` length, and then use that to get the `result`.

Show the `result` each second, you could use `setInterval` function with interval is **1000** (1 second).

Try this:

```js
var array = ['Bla','Blaa','Blabla','La'];

window.onload = function () {
  setInterval(function () {
    var index = parseInt(Math.random() * 10, 10) % array.length;
    var result = array[index];
    document.getElementById("paragraph").textContent = result;
  }, 1000);
};
```

```html
<p id="paragraph"></p>
```